# Doctrine ORM Entity class name is returning a Proxy class name

Tags: doctrine-orm, proxy-classes

I am currently retrieving the class name of my entities to save changes into a log. This happens in a listener:

In my service layer:

```php
$product = $line->getProduct();

$product->setAvailability($product->getAvailability() - $line->getAmount());
$em->persist($product);
```

the problem is that by doing following in a listener:

```php
$className = join('', array_slice(explode('\\', get_class($entity)), -1));
$modification->setEntidad($className);
```

The `$className` that is set into the modification is `miomioBundleEntityProductoProxy`.

How can I get the real class name for my entity, and not the proxy class name?

Comment: I neither have an idea of what your problem is nor what your question is. Please consider rephrasing your question so it can be understand.

Comment: @Sgoettschkes I've rewritten the question

Answer (score 2):

As the proxy class always extends from the real entity class:

```
class <proxyShortClassName> extends \<className> implements \<baseProxyInterface>
```

then, you can get it with [`class_parents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-parents.php) function:

```
if ($entity instanceof \Doctrine\Common\Proxy\Proxy) {
    $class = current(class_parents($entity)); // get real class
}
```

Especially useful when you don't have access to `EntityManager` instance.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you receive a proxy name when calling `get_class` on a proxy is quite normal, since proxies are a required concept to let the ORM and lazy loading of associations work.

You can get the original class name by using following API:

```php
$realClassName = $entityManager->getClassMetadata(get_class($object))->getName();
```

Then you can apply your own transformations:

```php
$normalizedClassName = join('', array_slice(explode('\\', $realClassName), -1));

$modificacion->setEntidad($normalizedClassName);
```

Comment: it's faster to use ClassUtils::getRealClass($className)

Comment: That's not going to retrieve the class name in all cases. You shouldn't do that manually as it's an implementation detail.